# Extend a Typescript class from an interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How do I extend a class with the properties of an interface in Typescript? I realize that this would necessarily leave the properties uninitialized.

My sole purpose is to reduce code redundancy. The property declarations that appear in the interface would identically appear in each class implementation. I'd rather maintain those properties centrally from just the interface.

I would like to write something like the following, but this is riddle with errors:

```
interface Spec {
    id: number;
}

class Model<S> {
    [K extends keyof S: string]: S[K];
}

class MyModel extends Model<Spec> {
    // id: number -- implicit
}
```

Instead, I find myself able to write this, which builds but doesn't do the job:

```
interface Spec {
    id: number;
}

class Model<S, K extends keyof S> {
    [K: string]: S[K];
}

class MyModel extends Model<Spec, keyof Spec> {
    // id: number -- implicit
}
```

It's clear that it doesn't do the job when I add `implements Spec` to MyModel:

```
class MyModel extends Model<Spec, keyof Spec> implements Spec {
    // id: number -- implicit
}
```

Because then I get the error, `Property 'id' is missing in type 'MyModel'`.

I'm not worried about leaving the interface properties uninitialized, because that can always be done from the constructor. The plethora of interfaces I'm dealing with is the greater nightmare.

NOTE: I'm using an underlying JS module to populate the spec properties, so the compiler won't necessarily complain if their declarations aren't provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to declare that a class has all the members of an interface:

```
class MyModel {
  // usual stuff
}
interface MyModel extends Spec { /* don't need to write anything here */ }
```

This feature is called *declaration merging*.

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you! However, I'd prefer that the dev get a compile-time warning when they forget to extend a spec. My example doesn't show the whole picture, as there will always be an associated spec. Is there any way to do that? (But this is a good fallback solution.)

Comment: Actually, I think this works! If any client of MyModel accesses a property of the associated spec and doesn't get it, the compiler complains; and if no client accesses the spec properties, there isn't even a runtime error. Perfect! (But it would be nice to report the error closer to the mistaken code.)

Comment: There are a few cases where I want a property to be readonly in the spec but writable in the model. Under this solution, it seems that I have to redeclare those properties (as writable) in each MyModel subclass of Model -- I can't do it once for all of them in Model.

Comment: And I solved the readonly problem by allowing the fields to be readonly throughout and using the magic bang notation: `this.createdAt! = new Date();` Nice! I'm one happy camper. Thank you sooooo much!